# Access Windows box from Linux

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, remote, vnc

How can I access a Windows box from Linux? With GUI or without. Something like VNC or SSH but for Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/)

> rdesktop is an open source client for Windows Remote Desktop Services, capable of natively speaking Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) in order to present the user's Windows desktop.

Answer (score 3):

SSH and VNC are platform-indipendent, so you can use them in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

Just use RDP client for Linux.
For example, if you are using linux:

```
$ sudo apt-get install rdesktop
$ rdesktop <WIN_IP_ADDRESS>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the same system in either direction you can run a VNC server on Windows:

- http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/winvnc.html
- http://www.tightvnc.com/