# How to remote access Windows from Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Access windows box from linux](https://superuser.com/questions/282216/access-windows-box-from-linux)

I use `mstsc.exe` for Windows to Windows connections.

Is there a way to remote access a Windows 7 machine from Ubuntu Linux using RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol)? What is the equivalent of `mstsc.exe` that I can easily run from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

rdesktop is the ticket my friend. It rocks.

```
apt-get install rdesktop
```

then

```
$ rdesktop [hostname]
```

and of course 'rdesktop --help' will explain how to use it. [Here's some extra docs](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=824710) for you. Those extra docs refer to "Terminal Server Client" too:

> Terminal Server Client (Applications > Internet > Terminal Server
>   Client) is a GUI front-end to VNC and rdesktop

You can install that through the software center and use it if the command-line calls are too disconcerting.

Comment: If its over a wan, `rdesktop -Pz hostname` enables bitmap caching and compression, making the thing much more bearable.

Comment: ssh won't do on-disk caching though, so you would at least benefit from the `-P` flag